# How to convert .dotm to .docm?

Tags: microsoft-word

I accidentally saved a `.docm` as `.dotm`, and now when I want to edit the document it opens as a new template with all the original macros stripped out. How to convert back from `.dotm` to `.docm`?

Renaming the file extension doesn't work.

Comment: Try opening the file with the `File` -> `Open` dialog, rather than just double-clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Explorer, right-click the *.dotm file and select `Open`. 
From within Word, use the File > Open dialog to open the *.dotm file.
Then use Save As command to save it as a *.docm. Once you've established that everything works as expected, you can delete the rogue *.dotm.